# How do I ensure active menu items are highlighted for Views with Better Exposed Filter arguments

Tags: routes, path-aliases, views

I'm using [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) on a clothing site. There are various types of products listed using Better Exposed Filters (to choose between Mens/Womens/Kids).

The Mens and Womens pages are variations on the same view.
The mens is at: `/product-type/all?tid_3%5B%5D=1`
The womens is at: `/product-type/all?tid_3%5B%5D=2`

This means that in each case the appropriate 'Better Exposed FIlter' checkbox is pre-selected.

**The problem**
Drupal treats both pages as the same address. Instead of making the "Womens" menu active items when on that page, it keeps the "Mens" menu item active.

How can I get around this, while ensuring that both "Mens" and "Womens" are the same view? I have already tried creating new URL aliases but Drupal does not allow me to do so for those URLS.

Comment: I am looking for something similar to this or maybe exactly the same thing. Have you looked in to "Contextual Filters" though? It would make your check-boxes somewhat unnecessary but would allow you to create separate path aliases that are clean urls. There's a ton of tutorials on it.